# Need to add a custom option in Ember Select

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I include a custom option (say, Quick Create) after the prompt in an Ember Select (with optgroups) ?
For example: I want my  options in ember select to look like this:

> ```
> Select
> Add
> Group1
>  Option1
>  Option2
> Group2
>  Option1
>  Option2
> ...
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ember select currently doesn't support option groups (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html), but for the "add" problem you could add an observer on whatever property you choose to value bind to and check if the selected option is "add".

Can't get jsfiddle to play nice with handlebars atm, but it might look something like...

Handlebars

```
{{view Ember.select contentBinding="App.options"
       valueBinding="App.Model.value"
       prompt="Select"}}
```

JS

```
var model = Em.Object.extend({
    value: '',
    valueObserver: function(){
        if(this.get('value') === 'Add')
            // add logic goes here
    }.observes('value')
});
```